# Searching Prolog Quine that doesnt use clause/2 or write/1?

Tags: prolog, quine

The simplest Prolog [Quine](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28Computerprogramm%29), that can reproduces
its own clause, reads as follows:

```
quine((quine(X) :- Y)) :-
    clause(quine(X), Y).

?- quine(Z).
Z =  (quine((quine(_22008):-_22004)):-clause(quine(_22008), _22004)).
```

Is there another Prolog Quine that doesn't use clause/2,
write/1, ..., i.e. dynamic database or input/output?

Can we write a Prolog program that searches such a Quine?

Comment: If you're willing to accept cyclic terms, maybe something like `quine(Z) :- Z = (quine(X) :- X = Z).`?

Comment: If I run it, I only get `?- quine(X).
X =  (quine(_2226):-_2226=X)`, the body does not reproduce., but the result should be `X = (quine(_1) :- _1 = (quine(_2) :- _2 = _1))`